# Creating hash of a struct in Solidity and JavaScript

Tags: solidity, web3js, hash

I have created a message hash in JavaScript using:

```
let message = {
        'message': 'Receiver closing signature',
        'sender': sender,
        'balance': value
};

message = web3.utils.toHex(message);
let messageHash = web3.utils.sha3(message);
```

How should I define the equivalent object in solidity, and what function should I use to get the same message hash.

Comment: Do you have to convert to hex first? That sounds like the hard part to replicate in Solidity...

Comment: Yes as  sha3 parameter should be A string to hash.

Comment: Right, but you could do something like `JSON.stringify(message)` instead...

Comment: Agree I can use JSON.stringify(message) ! How should we construct the same message at solidity side

Comment: So if in other words in below function, Need to construct mentioned sample message using the given input parameters.

How should I do it?
// Solidity 
        function convertToString(address _address,
                                 uint256  _number,
                                 string message ) public {
      
    // Message = "{"message":"This is Sample message","address":"0xf32a7ecb5Cd6521165d7099112222223568a4FE","number":"11"}"

}

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is to use the `abi.encode` method in solidity, and the equivalent `web3.eth.abi.encodeParameters` in web3.js.

Something like this:

**Solidity Source**

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract test{

    struct mStruct {
        string message;
        address sender;
        uint balance;
    }

    function testme() public pure returns(bytes32) {

        mStruct memory message = mStruct("Receiver closing signature", 0xCA35b7d915458EF540aDe6068dFe2F44E8fa733c, 100);
        return keccak256(abi.encode(message.message, message.sender, message.balance));
    }
}
```

Result:

> 0x4006e807f707d49e72276526e1106236184a868f6a142ca286ae0583556bacfb

**JavaScript Source**

```
message = {
    'message': 'Receiver closing signature',
    'sender': '0xCA35b7d915458EF540aDe6068dFe2F44E8fa733c',
    'balance': 100
};

encoded = web3.eth.abi.encodeParameters(['string', 'address', 'uint'],[message.message, message.sender, message.balance])

hash = web3.utils.keccak256(encoded)
```

Result:

> "0x4006e807f707d49e72276526e1106236184a868f6a142ca286ae0583556bacfb"

Comment: +1 that’s nice! I wasn’t aware of the abi object.

Comment: @Shawn Tabrizi .. you are awesome Bro... Liked the way u have moved the complexcity at web3 end from solidity .. .

++++1